# Ajax call to API not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from an API using Jquery's ajax(), but it doesn't work with this implemenation:

```js
$.ajax('http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json').done(function(data) {
  alert(1);
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After running the code the alert function doesn't work, so I concluded that the success callback function isn't working, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Could you see any error in console ?

Comment: No error in the console, just the alert function not being called

Comment: You should try to catch errors for ajax calls for this exact reason :)

Comment: @SalP. – Do share a demo so that one could figure out the issue...

Comment: Try including `.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)})` chained to `.done()`, check `console` for message

Comment: add the fail option to see is there is an error `$.ajax('http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json').done(yourfunction).fail(yourfailfunction)`

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&_=1468601253927. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: When I try your code I get the error "No Access-Control-Allowed-Origin header" in the console.

Comment: JSONP for the win.

Comment: Hmmm, when I test the code with the fail method in jsfiddle, it says that the mixed active content was blocked. Check out my jsfiddle instance here:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r962bL2m/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inspecting the server response headers, there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, this means that the server **doesn't allow cross-origin access**. Since you make a cross-origin HTTP request, your request will be rejected by the browser following the **Same-origin policy**:

> The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from
>   one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a
>   critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious
>   documents.

Look at your console  you will see the following error (Chrome):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

For more details please refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible for jsfiddle to request a Jquery module from the CDN because of the same origin policy?

Comment: No ! what I mean is you can't make an **ajax** request to a remote server who doesn't allow that !